# In Daniel 7:15, what is the meaning of the word נִדְנֶה?

Tags: word-study, daniel, aramaic

In Dan. 7:15, the Aramaic text states,

> <sup>טו</sup> אֶתְכְּרִיַּת רוּחִי אֲנָה דָנִיֵּאל בְּגוֹא נִדְנֶה וְחֶזְוֵי רֵאשִׁי יְבַהֲלֻנַּנִי

which the King James Version translates into English as,

> <sup>15</sup> I Daniel was grieved in my spirit in the midst of my body, and the visions of my head troubled me. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>

I’m curious about the word נִדְנֶה which is translated as “my body.” Rather than נִדְנֶה, I would have expected גִּשְׁמִי (“my body”) or perhaps even גֶּשֶׁם (“body”). What is the meaning of the word נִדְנֶה?

Comment: My uninformed instinct is to think that the word (literally "sheath" according to Strong's) might be used similar to the Shakespearean use of 'mortal coil' to refer to the body as the trappings of the spirit.  I'd also be interested in how people interpret the word נִדְנֶה here (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word spelt ndn in both Hebrew and Aramaic means "sheath" (for a sword). Aramaic ndnh means "its sheath" (with the pronominal suffix for the 3rd person singular). It is a loanword from Old Persian. Here in Dan. 7:15 it is used figuratively, of course. The body encompasses the soul in the same way that a sheath contains a sword.

http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/oneentry.php?lemma=ndn%232%20N&cits=all